# How prove this $p(p^2-2q)=q^3$

Tags: calculus

> let $p,q\in C$,and such this system
>   $$\begin{cases}
> p^2+p-q+\dfrac{1}{q}=0\\
> pq+q+\dfrac{p}{q}=0
> \end{cases}$$
>   show that
>   $$p(p^2-2q)=q^3$$
>   since
>   $$\begin{cases}
> p^2q+pq-q^2+1=0\\
> pq^2+q^2+p=0
> \end{cases}$$
>   for the two equation we have $$q^2(p+1)+p=0\Longrightarrow q^3=-\dfrac{pq}{p+1}$$
>   $$\Longleftrightarrow p(p^2-2q)=-\dfrac{pq}{p+1}\Longleftrightarrow (p+1)(p^2-2q)=-q$$
>   then I can't. Thank you

By the way: this problem is from this:

let $a,b(a\neq b)$ is $x^4+x^3=1$ roots,show that
$$(a+b)(a^2+b^2)=a^3b^3$$

my try: let $a,b,c,d$ is equation $$x^4+x^3-1=0$$ four roots,and have
$$\begin{cases}
a+b+c+d=-1\\
ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd=0\\
bcd+acd+abd+abc=0\\
abcd=-1
\end{cases}$$
and let $$a+b=p,q=ab,r=c+d,s=cd$$
then we have
$$\begin{cases}
p+r=-1\\
pr+q+s=0\\
qr+ps=0\\
qs=-1
\end{cases}$$
we only show that
$$p(p^2-2q)=q^3$$

Comment: Did you notice that,from the second equation, $p$ can be simply expressed as a function of $q$ ? This could help.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a,b$ be two distinct roots of $P(X)=X^4+X^3-1$. One has the 
factorization $P(X)=(X-a)(X^3+(a+1)X^2+(a^2+a)X+(a^3+a^2))$.
So
$$
b^3=-(a+1)b^2-(a^2+a)b-(a^3+a^2) \tag{1}
$$

and hence

$$
(ab)^3=\frac{a^3b^4-a^4b^3}{b-a}=
\frac{a^3(1-b^3)-(1-a^3)b^3}{b-a}=
\frac{a^3-b^3}{b-a}=-(a^2+ab+b^2)\tag{2}
$$

On the other hand, (1) yields

$$
(a+b)(a^2+b^2)=a^3+ab^2+(a^2)b+b^3=-b^2-ab-a^2  \tag{3}
$$

so that $(a+b)(a^2+b^2)=(ab)^3$ as wished. Note that the equality
is false when $a=b$.

Comment: How have this $$P(X)=(X-a)(X^3+(a+1)X^2+(a^2+a)X+a^3+a)$$,I know this $x^3$ and $a^3+a$,but how Found $X^2$and $X$the coefficient? Thank you

Comment: @chinamath In the identity $X^4+X^3-1=(X-a)(X^3+c_2X^2+c_1X+c_0)$, expand the right-hand side and identify coefficients

Comment: oh.Thank you very much,+1

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{cases}
p^2q+pq-q^2+1=0\\
pq^2+q^2+p=0
\end{cases}$

you already have :

$(p+1)(p^2-2q)=-q$

from 2nd one, you have:

$-p=q^2(p+1)$

multiply two equations, you get

$p(p^2-2q)=q^3$